# Botão de Exclusão e Campos Editaveis (PHP,SQL,HTML,CSS)

Tags: php, javascript, css, sql, html5

Sou nova aqui, estudante de Ciências da Computação e estágiaria de programação...

Não sei muito como funciona o fórum, mas tenho uma dúvida pertinente que já revirei o Google varias vezes e ainda não consegui resolver, mesmo que ela seja um tanto simples =(

Tenho um projeto para fazer e criei uma tabela em SQL e estou usando PHP, a parte de cadastros nessa tabelas, listagem dela e algumas funções de chamada de serviço funcionam... porém preciso criar um botão na listagem que exclui uma linha da tabela e tornar o campo de listagem editavel, mas não consigo fazer de jeito nenhum,alguém teria alguma dica ou orientação?

Obrigada!! 
Segue o código da página de listagem/alteração/exclusão:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> MENU DE AÇÔES</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>

<style>
#t{
font-family: arial;
text-align:center;

}
#z{
font-size:105%;
font-weight:bold;
font-style: oblique;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
}

body, 
.menu,
.sub-menu {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.clearfix:after{
content: '';
display: block;
clear: both;
height: 20;
line-height: 0;
font-size: 30;
visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
}
.menu,
.sub-menu {
   list-style: none;
background: #000;
}
.sub-menu {
background: #444;
}
.menu a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 20px;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 700;
}
.menu li {
   position: relative;
}
.menu > li {
float: left;
}
   .menu > li:hover {
    background: #444;
}
.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
div{
   font-family: arial;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<form style= "right:2%;left:80%; top:2% ; position:absolute"        name="frmBusca" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?a=buscar" >
<input type="text" name="palavra" />
<input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
</form>



<?php

/*
* EXCLUDE FROM WHERE 
* 
* UPDATE FROM WHERE 
* 
* 
* $_GET
* usar ID para selecionar o elemento 
*  
* 
*/

$acesso = mostra();
function mostra (){
$palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "asdf000";
$banco = "automoveis";

$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha, $banco);
if($conexao){
    $db=mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco);

} else {
    echo ("Erro ao conectar ao bando de dados");
    return false;
}
$String = "SELECT descricao,placa,codigoRenavam,anoModelo,anoFabricacao,cor,km,marca,preco,preco    Fipe FROM automovel ";
if($palavra != ''){
    $String .= "WHERE descricao LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR placa LIKE     '%".$palavra."%' OR codigoRenavam LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR anoModelo LIKE        '%".$palavra."%' OR anoFabricacao LIKE '%".$palavra."%' 
 OR cor LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR km LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR marca LIKE '                           %".$palavra."%' OR preco LIKE  '%".$palavra."%' OR precoFipe LIKE      '%".$palavra."%' ";
}
$String .= "ORDER BY descricao ";
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, $String);

echo '<table border = 10 bordercolor = "#000" cellpadding="25" width="100%" table style="table-layout: fixed ;">';
echo '<tr id = "z"><td> Descrição </td><td> Placa </td><td>RENAVAM</td><td>Ano do Modelo</td><td> Ano de Fabricação</td><td> Cor</td>
        <td> Kilometragem </td> <td> Marca</td> <td> Preço </td> <td> Preço FIPE </td> <td> Exclui </td></tr>';

while( $exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo "<h3> <tr > <td>" .$exibe['descricao']. "</td> "; 
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['placa']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['codigoRenavam']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['anoModelo']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['anoFabricacao']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['cor']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['km']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['marca']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['preco']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['precoFipe']. "</td>";
    echo"<td> </td>";"</tr><h3>";
}

echo '</table>';    
}
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, no botão de remover você pode colocar o ID do registro como atributo do botão e no evento de "click" você pode chamar um Ajax passando o ID do registro que você quer remover. O mesmo vale para deixar a tabela editável, quando acontecer o evento de click em qualquer item, você abre um input text no mesmo lugar onde foi clicado, e após a pessoa clickar fora você faz outro ajax de Update.

Comment: Você pode utilizar esse exemplo para a tabela editável. https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/editIcon.html
ai você só vai se preocupar com o Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Uma soloção, se eu percebi o que você quer, poderá ser esta.Apenas coloquei na marca.
Necessitará de fazer referencia a biblioteca de JQUERY.

> O exemplo em php (caso seja isso, será so replicar o input text para todos os `<td>`!

```
while( $exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo "<h3> <tr > <td>" .$exibe['descricao']. "</td> "; 
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['placa']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['codigoRenavam']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['anoModelo']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['anoFabricacao']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['cor']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['km']. "</td> ";
    echo "<td>  <input type='text' id='".$exibe['marca']."' name='marca' class='alterarMarca' disabled='true'></td>";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['preco']. "</td> ";
    echo " <td>" .$exibe['precoFipe']. "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='updateTable'>Alterar</a></td>";
    echo"<td> </td>";"</tr><h3>";
}
```

> JQUERY
>   Caso pretenda alterar esse campo entao terá de acrescentar o seguinte AJAX  ecriar a class update

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.updateTable', function(){
        $('.alterarMarca').prop('disabled',true);
        var ID= $(this).parents('tr').find('.ID').val();
        var marca= $(this).parents('tr').find('.alteramarca').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'classupdate.php',
                type: "POST",
                cache:false,
                data:{ID:ID, marca:Marca},
                async: false,
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
      });
     });
    </script>
```

Alguma duvida não hesite em questionar.